# Installing exmpp on Centos

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, exmpp

This might be a novice question, but how would I install exmpp on a Centos 6 box?

I've scoured the internet and I can't find a solution. 
I can't seem to build it, nor can I find a rpm that works either via yum.

Any ideas and/or installation steps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install exmpp in two ways. both will work

Installation via source

Download the source from the following [Source_Link](http://download.process-one.net/exmpp/)

```
cd /usr/local/src/

wget the source here.

tar -xvf file.tar.gz

cd exmpp*
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
make install
```

Installation complete.

Installation via git

git clone git://git.process-one.net/exmpp/mainline.git exmpp_mainline

```
cd exmpp_mainline
./configure
make
make install
```

Installation is complete.

There are few dependencies for the exmpp to get installed. Make sue that they are installed in the server.

1. Erlang/OTP
2. C compiler

   > gcc
3. XML parsing library

   > LibXML2
   >
   > Expat

Comment: thanks, I had two issues, firstly I never installed gcc. Then I realised autoconf version was a mismatch. Then it came to my attention that my Dev box was Centos 5.8 instead of 6. So after a update and your guidance, all looks fine.

Comment: So do you completed the installation? For gcc 'yum install gcc -y' will be enough :) Let me know if you finds any issues. :)